# unable to play youtube video on 2.3

Tags: android, youtube

I'm unable to open you tube into my application's webview on android 2.3 but on android 4.1 it works properly

here is the code

```
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    openWebLinkWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(false);
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled (true);
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    openWebLinkWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    openWebLinkWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code  in your YouTube video Activity  class

```
WebView web=new WebView(MyYouTubeActivity.this);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("youtube_link");
setContentView(mWebView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i faced this issue before this is because the feature of `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` is only available in **API version greater or equal to 11** and in `4.1` it is by default enabled (you can enable/disable this in manifest at application level).

Comment: Yes of course it will not work in 2.3 or API level 10 or below

Comment: thnx for quick reply.. i have tried both solutions but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like yours when playing on 2.3.3 
The following worked for me.

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.idWebView);       


    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getTouchables();
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    String emdLink = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_code;
    webView.loadUrl(emdLink);
```

Note: you should have `embed` + your video code.

Note also the above uses a deprecated call - in place of

```
            webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

it should be better to use (untested):

```
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Comment: hey now webview shows video in full screen mode but problem persists.